# Error in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I wanted to make sure whether the below config is right and as expected. Seems that HDFS capacity to be zero is unexpected..? How to fix it.?

```
[hduser@hadoop-vm03 bin]$ jps
25382 Jps
24427 NameNode
24768 JobTracker
24889 TaskTracker
24669 SecondaryNameNode
[hduser@hadoop-vm03 bin]$ hadoop dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used%: ?%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think all the Hadoop daemon should run in the machine where you are executing jps, you don't seem to have datanode daemon running. When there is no datanode obviously the capacity would be 0. Please check the datanode log to figure out the issue.